# Restore sitecollection from content database belongs to different sharepoint farm and domain

Tags: 2013, restore

i have a content database from different sharepoint farm and different domain, and this content database has one root site collection

i want to restore this site collection into my development farm which has differenct sharepoint farm and different domain compare to backup of content database.

what aret the steps recommended for above requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Process is as follows:

1. Create an SP Web App.
2. Detach the content DB that was created as default, using powershell.

   Dismount-SPContentDatabase 12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890abcdef

   REF: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607764.aspx
3. Restore the backup to DEV SQL.
4. Attach the Backup of the content DB from another domain.

   Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication http://sitename

Ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx

Important note, if you have custom solutions you need to deploy them before mounting. There might be some specific setting in web.config that you might need to recreate.

After mounting you can add  your user as SCA and navigate to the site. 
If you need to migrate some users use the

```
Move-SPUser cmdlet
```